# Using .htaccess to both handle non-existent paths and convert http to https

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to achieve the following using .htaccess

1 - convert all http requests to https
2 - capture any nonexistent paths, and redirect to a existing path, passing the nonexistent path by some means (as a querystring, hash, via envelope or post variable) for interpretation.
3 - Be able to do both the above, for specific folders.

Currently I've got #2 working by passing the nonexistent path as a hash, which gets interpreted by client side scripting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SomeSubFolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \#$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

It works to the extent that
http://[somedomain.com]/[ExistingPath]/[NonExistingPath]

becomes

http://[somedomain.com]/[ExistingPath]/#[NonExistingPath]

(i.e. the non-existing path becomes a hash tagged on to the existing path, which subsequently gets interpreted via JS)

If there's a less quirky way to do that, I'm all ears.

So far I've not been able to convert http requests to https and while at the same time protecting the above functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SomeSubFolder/
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect non-existant path
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \#$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

When you are the sure the rule is working fine ,Change `R` to `R=301` in the https  rule to make the redirection permanent (browsers and search engines cached) .

Comment: Indeed, that did it.  Completely obvious... but only after you posted it.  Thank you!

Comment: Extra question re 'less quirky way to do this': I tried passing the original URI to a header or a post variable so that instead of doing the hash thing, I'd pick up the 'original url' in a manner that PHP or JS could read.  Is something like that possible?